# Can anyone recommend a good PDF reading library for .Net?

Tags: pdf

Can anyone recommend a good component for reading PDFs from .Net?  Specifically, I want to read all the metadata of the document, including all the document properties (title, author, etc.).  *I really don't need to read the actual content of the document.*

Commercial products are fine.

I read about PDFBox (for Java), but that seems painful.   I've also been to [this page](http://jadn.co.uk/w/ReadPdfUsingCsharp.htm), but nothing great jumped out at me.

Answer (score 4):

What about [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/)? As far as I know its the definitive pdf library.

Comment: It's pretty good at writing them, but last time I checked not so much at reading.

Answer (score 3):

For .Net there is the [PDF Lib](http://pdflib.codeplex.com/) (current version 1.3). It looks fine (but i've not tested it yet).

Comment: It works well, I've just used it (version 2.1).

Answer (score 3):

[Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) (I work for the company) may be used to accomplish the task.

Here is sample code:

```
using (PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument("file.pdf"))
{
    string author = document.Info.Author;
    string subject = document.Info.Subject;
    string title = document.Info.Title;
    string keywords = document.Info.Keywords;
    // ...
}
```

Beyond that the library can do many other things. There are [samples for common tasks](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples) available online.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [ABC.pdf](http://www.websupergoo.com/)?  It definitely does was you want, reading pdf document properties - [see here](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf7net/source/4-examples/14-setprops.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [CoherentPDF](http://www.coherentpdf.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend [Amyuni PDF Creator ActiveX](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreatoractivex), a PDF editor ActiveX control (32 bit and 64 bit versions are available) and [Amyuni PDF Creator .Net](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator/features.html).
*Disclaimer: I am part of the development team of this product.*

Comment: Does Amyuni webkit honor page break in HTML while generating PDF. I have a huge html with multiple pages however when i create a pdf with Amyuni it creates 1 long page without any page breaks.

Comment: @user428747 Did you try changing the options in the method WKPDFOpenURL? The parameter called pageRenderingOptions controls whether the library will generate several pages or just one.