# How to extract title from .pdf file using c#

Tags: c#, pdf

I know that for Python such solution exist already ([pypdf](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/)). But I hope that someone could suggest some library for C# for this issue.

Comment: Please define *title* in a PDF?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1276028/352101

Comment: For "title" I mean what you can see in window title when you open some .pdf file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A commonly used library for manipulating PDF files in .NET  is [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) which is a port of the [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) library. Here's an example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("test.pdf");
        var title = reader.Info["Title"];
        Console.WriteLine(title);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) (Disclaimer: I work for the company) may be used to accomplish the task.

Please take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656351/can-anyone-recommend-a-good-pdf-reading-library-for-net/6127353#6127353) for [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/656351/249690).

Beyond that the library can do many other things of course.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
http://glenswords.wordpress.com/2007/07/16/extract-the-title-of-a-pdf-using-c/
```

Comment: +1.  You might want to add something between the `<<` and the `/Title` since stuff like `/CreationDate` might show up first.  This is definitely cheating and is a dirty rotten hack (and using the solution as written is probably a bad idea), but it has the advantage over the other solutions of not requiring a giant library for a rather tiny feature.

Comment: I completely agree with Brian as a light solution for tiny feature

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to iTextSharp is PDFBOX.  See [CodeProject Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/pdf2text.aspx) for instructions on using it.  This is slightly ugly since you're basically running a C# Java VM, but it's actually really easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

If by "Title" you mean the Title keyword in the metadata in the Trailer of the PDF, then you can use a number of different tools.  iTextSharp will do it, although I don't know the API well enough to give you code.

If you use dotImage, from [Atalasoft](http://www.atalasoft.com) (where I work, and incidentally, I wrote this code), you can do this:

```
PdfDocumentMetadata metadata  = PdfDocumentMetadata.FromStream(sourceStream);
Console.WriteLine("Title is \"{0}\"", metadata.Title);
```

This class also gives you Author, Subject, Keywords, Creator, Producer, CreationDate, ModificationDate, Trapped, and custom fields.

If you're talking about finding the title in XMP embedded in the PDF - well, that's a different beast entirely and I don't yet have support for pulling that out.

Comment: Thank you very much for your posting. Your solution seems to be the most attractive for my issue from commercial library, on my point of view.